# Reading a .js file into R

Tags: javascript, r, json

I dowloaded the file from my huawei notes from the cloud, and I want to make an R object with the notes on R.
The files that one downloads is a zip file that unloads a folder of folders,
each with an html file and a js file.
I have no idea how to load the file, but aparently the content of the note is in the js file, I know because I can see the things I've written in the notes in the js file when I open it with a text editor.
Here's what is written in it:(and example from one note

```
var data = {"content":{"first_attach_name":"","need_reminded":0,"data5":"{\"data1\":\"\"}","data4":"0","created":11111111111111,"unstruct_uuid":"11111111111111","data3":"","has_attachment":0,"is_lunar":0,"title":"A morning of the slag ravine\n","version":"25","content":"Text|A morning of the slag ravine ","has_todo":0,"html_content":"<note><element type=\"Text\">A morning of the slag ravine </element></note>","prefix_uuid":"4r$q$4d33$9$","modified":1597090752972,"tag_id":"r5$r5","delete_flag":0,"favorite":0,"mContentType":0,"fold_id":13}}
```

I first tried to read the file with jsonlite, becuase the file is named json.js, but I got nothing:

```
> jsonlite::read_json("A:/Path/json.js"
+ )
Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : 
  lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       var data = {"content":{"first_a
                     (right here) ------^
>
```

When I read it with readlines I get a warning:

```
 readLines(system.file("A:/Path/json.js", package="js"), warn = FALSE)
character(0)
Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  file("") only supports open = "w+" and open = "w+b": using the former
>
```

I can read the file like this:

```
readLines("A:/Path/Notes/Note_number/json.js")
Warning message:
In readLines("A:/Path/Notes/Note_number/json.js") :
  incomplete final line found on 'A:/Path/Notes/Note_number/json.js'
> eg
[1] "var data = {\"content\":{\"first_attach_name\":\"\",\"need_reminded\":0,\"data5\":\"{\\\"data1\\\":\\\"\\\"}\",\"data4\":\"0\",\"created\":1597090752980,\"unstruct_uuid\":\"148162573320959249\",\"data3\":\"\",\"has_attachment\":0,\"is_lunar\":0,\"title\":\"A morning of the slag ravine\\n\",\"version\":\"25\",\"content\":\"Text|A morning of the slag ravine \",\"has_todo\":0,\"html_content\":\"<note><element type=\\\"Text\\\">A morning of the slag ravine </element></note>\",\"prefix_uuid\":\"47f5d80d$e8e9$4d33\",\"modified\":1597090752,\"tag_id\":\"\",\"delete_flag\":0,\"favorite\":0,\"mContentType\":0,\"fold_id\":13}}"
```

I also tried this:

```
sonlite::fromJSON(readLines("A:/Path/json.js"))
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       var data = {"content":{"first_a
                     (right here) ------^
>
```

the notes are over 600 and have several categories.
(The folder ID part in the json.js file).
I'd like to be able to make a list of every note as a list; that contains, tilte, content, and folder ID.
this is what I was trying:

```
eg2<-list.files("A:/path/Notes")
eg3<-list()
for(i in 1:length(eg2)){
  eg4<-paste0("A:/path/Notes",
              "/",eg2[i],"/json.js")
  ak2<-jsonlite::fromJSON(readLines(eg4)
  eg3[[i]]<-ak2
}
```

Of course this doesn't work yet, but I put it to exemplify my final goal.
help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **V8** package to read this file:

```r
library(V8)
cx <- v8()
cx$source("data.js") # now the variable 'data' is defined in V8
cx$get("data") # so we can get it
# $content
# $content$first_attach_name
# [1] ""
# 
# $content$need_reminded
# [1] 0
# 
# $content$data5
# [1] "{\"data1\":\"\"}"
# 
# $content$data4
# [1] "0"
# 
# $content$created
# [1] 1.111111e+13
#
# ......
```

If you want to use `jsonlite::read_json`, you have to remove `var data =`.